# Parse/replace XML attribute/element with a value pulled from database

Tags: mysql, xml

Any way we can parse/replace the tag/attribute's value with a value pulled from database? 
I was thinking about something like 
$sql = "SELECT model FROM `Vendor_tbl` WHERE id=\'1\'";
then use the value of $sql to replace $data_to_be_replaced in my XML

Here's my XML and

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
 <head>
  <column width="180" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">Vendor</column>
  <column width="180" type="coro" align="left" sort="int">Model</column>
  <column width="*" type="edtxt" align="left" sort="str">Serial Number</column>
 </head>
 <row id="1">
  <cell><![CDATA[Vendor]]></cell>
  <cell xmlcontent="1" editable="0"> $data_to_be_replaced
                    <option value="Dell">DELL</option> 
                    <option value="HP">HP</option> 
                    <option value="Toshiba">Panasonic</option> 
        </cell> 
    <cell><![CDATA[SN123456]]></cell>
 </row>
 
</rows>
```

So what I am looking is $data_to_be_replaced to be replaced by a value that I pull from database. Thank you

Comment: You need to specify a programming language and the code that presents this to a user.

Comment: Sorry - i am using PHP and MySQl - Thank you

Comment: My since condolences on PHP. Showing the code would help however.

Comment: I am newbie and still learning and I just need some pointers ... nothing else